# On hover to push 2 sides

Tags: html, css

When I hover image it goes shrinking like this
[result 1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2VGD.jpg)
But I want the opposite result like a Netflix
[result 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WlTq.png) Please help me with this problem.

```
    <div class="card">
         <a href="#" data-lightbox="inline">
              <img class="card-post m-0 p-0" src="img/vinland_08.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
         </a>
         <div class="fanOverlay">
              <small class="card-title">episode 5</small><br>
              Son of Troll<br>
         </div>
    </div>

.fanOverlay{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
opacity: 0;
transition: .5s ease;
border-radius: 15px;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.card:hover .fanOverlay{
    opacity: 1;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
.card:hover{
    transition: 250ms all;
    margin: 0 40px;
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Comment: Could you post all the html+css code of that row?

Comment: @MatteoZanini now there is a bug like this https://imgur.com/lP4INEE  You can see full code from here http://beta.mnfansubs.net/design/

Comment: Instead of owl plugin, try to take a look at [this](https://codepen.io/Raddy/pen/NojQmd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's should be a better way, so take this just as an example; here's a list of modifies I made to your page, to get the result:

Add some **left margin** for first image (padding left for the first div, margin left for the second):

```
<div class="section notopborder notopmargin nobottommargin p-3 noborder dark"
     style="padding-left: 5px !important;">
   ...
<div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); transition: all 0.25s ease 0s; width: 2834px;margin-left: 12px;">
```

Add margin between items (increasing data margin to 20)

```
<div id="oc-posts" class="owl-carousel posts-carousel carousel-widget owl-loaded owl-drag" data-loop="false" data-margin="20" data-nav="true" data-pagi="false" data-items-xs="1" data-items-sm="2" data-items-md="3" data-items-lg="3" data-items-xl="4">
```

and adding this style to get the fade in and fade out zoom, on hover

```
.owl-item.active{
   transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.owl-item.active:hover{
   transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Comment: Hi,
I tried to like your advice and it's almost done. But there is an error that occurred like this https://imgur.com/uGPgPhz and I solved it to create one blank item in the last.
This answer was very helpful to me. Thank you for your kind help!